# golang cgo can't export variables by build mode c-shared

Tags: go, cgo

I am trying to develop in the cgo a plug-in of sudo.

https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.15/sudo_plugin.man.html

export the struct to the global scope of policy_plugin.

> A policy plugin must declare and populate a `policy_plugin` struct in the global scope.

Do you have an explanation of what that means?

#### export_test.go

```
package main

/*
#include "sudo_plugin.h"
#include <stddef.h>
*/
import "C"

func main() {
}

// don't worked
//export policy
var policy = &C.struct_policy_plugin{
    C.SUDO_POLICY_PLUGIN,
    C.SUDO_API_VERSION,
    nil,
    nil,
    nil,
    nil,
    nil,
    nil,
    nil,
    nil,
    nil,
    nil,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears buildmode `c-shared` only exports function entries, not variables.
While [the design doc](https://golang.org/s/execmodes) does not state this explicitly, it does not talk about variables explicitly either.

The [`cmd/cgo` manual](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) also does not mention variables explicitly but seems to imply that the special `//export ...`  comments apply to functions only.

What you could supposedly do about this is declare your external variable on the C side—after defining and expoting the necessary Go functions, like this:

"callbacks.go":

```
package main

import "C"

//export real_fn
func real_fn(x C.int) C.int {
    return 42
}
```

"main.go":

```
package main

/*
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int (*fn) (int x);
} foo;

extern int real_fn(int);

foo xyzzy = {
    0,
    real_fn,
};
*/
import "C"

func main() {
}
```

Now after running `go build -buildmode=c-shared` you can explore the generated library and see the `xyzzy` symbol available there:

```
cshared% nm -g cshared | grep -E 'xyzzy|real_fn'
0000000000061330 T _cgoexp_4f8dd74b8333_real_fn
00000000000b42c0 T real_fn
00000000003274d0 D xyzzy
```

A note: if you're about using callbacks you have to put them into a separate file (or files)—this appears to be a quirk of `cgo`.

Comment: Thank you kindly answer.
I did not think of such a method.
I'll try!