# Export a variable when building a shared object using cgo

Tags: c, go, cgo

I want to build a .so library using Go/Cgo with options `go build -buildmode=c-shared`.
Functions exports well, but I cannot export variables. I need to realize an API, which works by calling a void function, which sets up values of various global properties. Something like this:

```
var (
    Gval1 int
    Gval2 string
    //GvalN
)

func f(){
    Gval1 = 1
    Gval2 = "qwerty"
}
```

The client of .so lib will run f(); and after that, it can get variables by addressing their names. How can I export them?
I had tried to do a trick like this: [golang cgo can't export variables by build mode c-shared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36212246/golang-cgo-cant-export-variables-by-build-mode-c-shared), but there was no success (example returns always 0, not 42).
How can I export variables (numbers and strings)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can export variables, only functions.

The [go build](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Build_modes) documentation says:

```
-buildmode=c-shared
    Build the listed main package, plus all packages it imports,
    into a C shared library. The only callable symbols will
    be those functions exported using a cgo //export comment.
    Requires exactly one main package to be listed
```

Where the [cgo docs says](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/#hdr-C_references_to_Go)

```
Go functions can be exported for use by C code in the following way:
```

I guess you can write a function that returns the variable value.